# How to include a conditional column in a mysql query list?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 mysql tables: *users", "groups", "community".

- "users": uid, username, password, etc.
- "groups": gid, group_name, created, etc.
- "community": cid, uid(foreign), gid(foreign)

Now I'd like to list all the groups with their gid, groups_name, created, etc. attributes (dynamically). Thats fine. But I also would like to add a column that shows if a specific user is a member of the group.

**Like this:** (this table is true for a specific user, e.g.: uid = 4)

```
gid | group_name | created | ismember
1   | g1         | 2001    | true
2   | g2         | 2003    | true
3   | g3         | 2010    | false
...
```

It's important, that a group is only shown once. The user is logged in, so we know its "uid".

**These are my two mysql fragments:**

```sql
//get groups with their uids shown.
SELECT groups.*, community.uid
FROM groups, community
WHERE groups.gid = community.gid;

//get user-joined groups
SELECT groups.*
FROM groups
WHERE gid IN (
  SELECT gid
  FROM community
  WHERE uid = " . $uid . "
);
```

So is there a way to do this with only one mysql query? Or do I have to separate somehow the two requests and work with php if clauses? If so, how should I?

Comment: It's actually not clear what you are asking... Your example data has 3 separate users, and three separate groups - which gives us no real context to how you deal with users with multiple groups... Are you saying you want an array of ALL groups, but an indicator that shows whether they are a member of it or not?

Comment: I corrected that "uid" to "gid". It should be clear now. If it still lacks some info, do tell. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outerjoin like THIS sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd596/4/0

then anything with null uid they aren't a member of

Comment: probably need to further edit this query to include uid = :uid (where :uid is your php variable for uid

Comment: Thats the same as my first mysql query fragment. It doesn't solve alone what I wrote in the "like this" example.

Comment: the only difference with what you want and the above is, instead of "false" it returns null

Comment: I still don't see, how it will show if the logged in user is a member of the group or not. Also, a group should only be listed once.

Comment: Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1487c/2/0 - you'll see you actually pass in the uid of the logged in user... It only returns the group once, as I imagine gid is a primary key (therefore cannot exist multiple times) and will only return community.uid IF the uid for the group exists in the community table. Perhaps if you post your real model and the PHP you are using, I can help more - the reality is; no one here cares about your source and it's likely nothing groundbreakingly new that anyone would want to steal it

Comment: You're right, this one works! I should look up JOIN as it seems I don't know its real potential... Many thanks!